# Battery Charger - Design of Circuit

Tags: mosfet, batteries, transformer, battery-charging, igbt

Im Designing a Lead-Acid Battery charger, dont't needed that this charger it's the most sophisticated one.

- As you can see in the attached image, It only consist of a power transformer, a rectification and then directly to the battery, taking advantage of the ESR of the battery. As you see, there are parts in the circuit that I can control, before the transformer, after the transformer and after the rectification circuit. Wich one you will choose? Why? Considering that the logic part of the control circuit its controlled by a PIC, so i have PWM output, or a simple ON/OFF output.
- I'm actually doing it by controlling before the transformer, with a relay, but this generate lot of spikes, and has mechanic parts, without saying that the relay it's more expensive than a IGBT, SCR, MOSFET, etc.
- Considering all everything I said, I need the most robust, and cheaper way to do it, with this I mean that it's efficient, that can't fail.

The transformer can be up to 50VAC - 40Amps.

[image]

- Battery Specs: As i said, this isnt't only for 1 battery, but yes the same type of batteries, all Lead-Acid batteries, that can go between 12v-48v, and 10A-400A. They are charged at 10% of the total current capacity, so if it's a 400A battery, the transformer is 40A.
  The way of charging them depends on the circuit you will propose. Now I'm charging it with an ON/OFF output of the microcontroller, and then the relay, this goes in the control circuit 1 place.

Comment: So what are you proposing for the 3 control sections?  It would also be good to include the specifications of the battery.

Comment: I only propose to use one of them, but i put the three so you can know that i can use any of them...  I added the spec of the battery

Comment: 48 volts and 400 amps is over 19 kW <-- how do you intend to find an AC supply that can deliver in the region of 20 kW?

Comment: @Andyaka As i said, the battery will charge at 0.1C, so it will be a 40Amps transformer, not 400A